# How to turn off "The message was checked..." email signature in Nod32 antivirus version 4?

Tags: email, anti-virus, nod32

By default Nod32 antivirus (as well as many others) inserts its signature to every message it checks. IMHO it is completely useless waste of traffic, ink and paper (as many companies use to print significant messages). As aI can see, it is very often to see an extra page printed having only a piece of AV signature on it and no useful information.

How to disable this signature without disabling E-mail check? I couldn't find the option in Nod32 4 settings.

Comment: Good question, however I'd expect this to be hard coded - after all it's free advertising for the anti virus software.

Comment: @ChrisF, Nod32 is not any kind of a free.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of free to you, but free to the company!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under the Email Client protection setting. You can turn it completely off or just append the message to infected emails. YOU can push out a config file to all the clients to turn it off because it would add multiple signatures when people sent an email to someone else in the company. It adds one when you send an email and when you receive it.

Comment: Excuse me, colleagues, but even though I accept the solution as it sounds reasonable, I can't testify that it works as I have had no chance to test it actually.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to turn off these signatures (or "tags") in NOD32 anti-virus:

[How do I add or remove the "checked by ESET" notification tags that are appended to my email? (4.x)](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2105)

I've seen similar options in other AV scanners (such as AVG) so it's probably often possible, just not turned off by default.

Answer (score 1):

It's under `Settings/Active Protection`, then go to `Settings of the Mail Shield`, then go to `Behavior` and uncheck `Insert note into clean message (outgoing)`.